# Rest calls-Large amount of data between calls

Tags: java, rest

We are using Rest using Jersey. There are few scenarios where server(WAS 8.5) sends large amount of data to client, which is RCP application. In some cases data is so huge(150MB) in xml format that client gets an `OutOfMemoryError` exception.
I have below questions

1. How much size is increased when java object is converted in xml?
2. How we can send large java object to client and still use rest calls?

Comment: 1) depends on the used XML schema. 2) How is big amount of data related to REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Tough question to answer without seeing the XML schema, I've seen well designed schemas that result in tight, lean XML, and others that are a mess and very bloated. To test it write some test code that serializes your Java objects to a `byte[]` and compare it's size to the XML payload you currently produce.

2) Might be worth looking into a chunking process, 150MB is pretty large for a single payload. Also are you using GZIP compression for this already? Also may be worth looking at [Fast Infoset](https://fi.java.net/). Basically it's a binary encoding for XML that generally helps reduce the size of an XML Document.